# duplicate javascript code -

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a javascript that I downloaded off the net. This works great. My problem is I now require to use this same script but on three instances on the page? how can I duplicate or edit this javascript code in order to acheive this.

To give you a background, I have a dropdown list, that onchange calls the below function to populate a table with mysql data without page refresh. the script shows info from another page, getpersonsformedical.php.

I now have two other pages that I want to show on the same page using the same javascript. namely
getjobsformedical.php and getrisksformedical.php.

Any help would be appreciated. (apologies my javascript is not that great).

Can I just duplicate the code in another script tag? but then how do I call multiple onchange events for a single tag onclick. All three of these pages must be called from the single onclick.

I understand that there are other ways of doing this but if we could stivck to this methodology it would be appreciated.

To clarify, I need one onchage event to display three seperate php pages(with mysql data) in three seperate .

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER**

Thanks to dystroy, complete working script is:

```
<script> 
function showUser(userNumber, str, target, page) {  
  if (str=="")  {  
       document.getElementById(target + userNumber).innerHTML=''; 
     return;  
    }    
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {  
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)   {  
        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;  
      }  
    }  
    xmlhttp.open("GET",page+"?q="+str,true);  
    xmlhttp.send();  
  }  

    function showThreeSections(userNumber, str) { 
    showUser(userNumber, str, 'a', 'getpersonsformedical.php'); 
    showUser(userNumber, str, 'b', 'getjobsformedical.php'); 
    showUser(userNumber, str, 'c', 'getrisksformedical.php'); 
    }
</script>
```

outputted to divs:

```
<div align="left" id="a"><font color=gray>Person Assignment will be shown here</font></div>
<div align="left" id="b"><font color=gray>Person Jobs will be shown here</font></div>
<div align="left" id="c"><font color=gray>Person Risks will be shown here</font></div>
```

Thanks and Regards,
Ryan

Comment: You don't need to duplicate this script, as the function `showUser` takes parameters. Just duplicate the `<SELECT NAME=medcondition3 id=medcondition3 onchange="showUser(1, this.value)">`.

Comment: Hi @dystroy, but the script contains the PHP page which is referenced: getpersonsformedical.php. I want to get the info from page getjobsformedical.php and getrisksformedical.php. all three pages need to get pulled into existing page. In addition the one single select tag must call all three pages via the script. Thanks for prompt reply. appreciated

Comment: Add the page url as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Thanks @MAtt, can you elaborate at all. Apologies if this is something simple. Thanks,

Comment: PHP's `ext/mysql` (the `mysql_*` family) is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  Please use [something else](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have in the HEAD element of your HTML page the script, only once, but taking another argument : the name of the page.

And a second function could call the first one three times with the different arguments.

Something like this :

```
<HEAD>
 ... other things

<script>
function showUser(userNumber, str, page) { 
  if (str=="")  { 
      return; 
    }   
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)   { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText; 
      } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET",page+"?q="+str,true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  } 

  function showThreeSections(userNumber, str) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML='';
      showUser(userNumber, str, 'getpersonsformedical.php');
      showUser(userNumber, str, 'page2.php');
      showUser(userNumber, str, 'page3.php');
  }
</script>
```

Note that the big function **adds** to innerHTML instead of cleaning it.

And then you can have this select :

```
<SELECT NAME=medcondition3 id=medcondition3 onchange="showThreeSections(1, this.value)">
```

But this solution is probably bad : you should probably have different target divs to fill instead of just one. Hard to say without redesigning (or at least studying) the whole page.

---

EDIT :

If you want to target different divs, you should :

1) have three divs. For example

```
<div id=a1></div>
<div id=b1></div>
<div id=c1></div>
```

2) modify the code for example like this :

```
<script>
function showUser(userNumber, str, target, page) { 
  if (str=="")  { 
       document.getElementById(target + userNumber).innerHTML='';
     return; 
    }   
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)   { 
        document.getElementById(target + userNumber).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
      } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET",page+"?q="+str,true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  } 

  function showThreeSections(userNumber, str) {
      showUser(userNumber, str, 'a', 'getpersonsformedical.php');
      showUser(userNumber, str, 'b', 'page2.php');
      showUser(userNumber, str, 'c', 'page3.php');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Just make sure your IDs are not all the same. They have to be unique on the page, e.g. `medcondition1`, `medcondition2` and `medcondition3`.

Comment: Hi @dystroy, you are 100%, I have seperate divs for each page. I have edited question with complete page script. this shows threee different divs, each of which need to be populated by a seperate page. this is all driven off one onchange event in one select tag. Thanks,

Comment: You're welcome. You may have noticed that in my sample I removed the compatibility with IE5 & IE6. I'm not sure there is a point in maintaining this compatibility in one point of the code as it's not probable a site you make today will be compatible with IE6 anyway. But it's up to you to check this requirement still makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, perfect. youa re 1005 right. how do I get each page to display in seperate div? Thanks again.

Comment: I added a possible way to do this. But you must refine it to your page, looking at the whole picture.

Comment: Hi @dystroy, made the changes as per your code, thanks again. when selecting a value from the dropdown list and triggering hte onchange event, nothing is happening. any ideas? I updated my question to show the current page syntax. Thanks, Ryan

Comment: Are you sure you call `showThreeSections` in your select and not `showUser` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13315/discussion-between-smudger-and-dystroy)

Answer (score 2):

Before `xmlhttp.open` make a if function like this,

```
if(str == str){
    var page = "getjobsformedical.php?q="+str;
}
else{
    var page = "getrisksformedical.php?q="+str;
}
```

and then,

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",page,true);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)   {
    if(str == 'getjobsformedical.php'){
        document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText; 
    }
    elseif(str == 'getrisksformedical.php'){
        document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText; 
    }
    elseif(str == 'page3.php'){
        document.getElementById("txtHint3").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @itsme, problem is I still havent defined where these pages will be displayed in the script. Each page must go to a different div. first div is <div id="txtHint1">, the second is <div id="txtHint2"> and third is <div id="txtHint3">. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @itsme, appreciate teh help.